# How to delay loading of RecyclerView items when it is present in ViewPager2 in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity, android-viewpager2

I am using ViewPager2 to show data in fragments using RecyclerView inside respective fragment. There are 2 fragments. Each fragment contains 1 RecyclerView. Everything works fine, just one small problem, when I start activity which contains this ViewPager2, then if there are large number of items present then activity starts very slow. I know there are other solutions for this whole scenario for example reducing complex UI using ConstraintLayout, etc. But in my case I optimized all of that and still my activity startup time is slow.

So now I want to do the things in following way:

1. Load activity -> Show loading... TextView -> Wait for some time before calling notifyDatasetChanged() of inner RecyclerView

So I am doing this using:

```
  final MaterialTextView loadingMTV = findViewById(R.id.loadingMTV);
    loadingMTV.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadingMTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerViewAdapter.setTasks();
            completedRecyclerViewAdapter.setTasks();

            //setTasks() will contain notifyDatasetChanged() related logic
        }
    },500);
```

So it will delay inner content loading by 500 milliseconds. Now my activity startup time is as usual. Every thing works fine. Just one problem, I used 500 milliseconds as a delay time. I don't want this hardcoded value. So how to use proper delay time in this whole case?

Comment: how slow, and how large your data set is?

Comment: I added one TextView in my layout and then after finding that textview I added one runnable in its post() that will run after 10 miliseconds. And in that runnable I fetched recyclerview records. And by using this way, I solved delayed activity loading problem. My dataset is not that much huge but onbind() of recyclerview adapter is too complex. So I also simplified that code.

Comment: How ever complex it is, we should not fix it my adding extra delay, can you please tell us how did you measure the delay and came up with that time? Because there might be something small in your code which might be the cause of all these and now after adding a delay it is becoming more complex and in future it might produce some other issues.

Comment: I just lazyloading recyclerview data. First I load empty recyclerview and showing "fetching" textview. Then after that I am loading actual data in post() of that textview inside runnable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Creation of components inside the activity - the process of creating the activity itself, so until all internal Views are created, the Activity itself will not be created. [Read more here](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle)
2. Such problems are solved by transferring complex and lengthy computations to separate threads. You can use out-of-the-box asynchronous communication mechanisms such as RxJava. Thus, on another thread, you create View-components, and on the UI thread you only display them and interact with them.

Comment: Is there any way to create empty fragments first and then thereby add recyclerview to that fragment and then load data thereafter? So that activity can start quickly as possible because of that 2 blank fragments?

Comment: This is rarely practiced. The best option is to use async. Consider RxJava or Looper/Handler or java.lang.threads

Comment: In my case, I found that user interface creation of RecyclerView item is taking too much time. That is, data which I want to load in RecyclerView becomes available quickly but RecyclerView's item's UI takes too much time. So in my case which one is preferrable?